# How to add text overlay to each image added via razor?

Tags: css, image, razor

I need to add a number overlay to each image that is added via my razor code. The image is being generated through razor via parameters from my SQL database.

The number should ideally increase with each image addition, but that much I can do by myself.

Here is the code...with this combination, I am unable to use Javascript. It just adds an image to viewBox with the image source and style passed from the db table.

```
<div class="col-10 viewBox">

            @foreach (var x in Model.Structures)
            {
                    <img src="@x.ImageSource" style="@x.Style" />

            }

</div>
```

I'm beginning to think what I am trying to do is impossible, or just not possible in the way that I want. Please send all suggestions my way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the number inside a label and `float` it to `right`

```
   <div class="col-10 viewBox">
    <span class="label label-default pull-right">SOME NUMBER</label>
                @foreach (var x in Model.Structures)
                {
                        <img src="@x.ImageSource" style="@x.Style" />

                }

    </div>
```